# Visual Studio 2015 autoprefixer

Tags: visual-studio, sass, less, autoprefixer

I find Web Essentials autoprefixer not auto enough - I need to manually say it to add prefixes. Also it doesn't offer me prefixes when I'm writing `.less` or `.scss`.

Is there any extension or option to make it automatically add prefixes on css compilation from `.less` or `.scss` stage?

I've tried Web Compiler extension, but it doesn't support prefixing for sass, and says that it supports prefixing for less, but I've tried enabling autoprefix in compilerconfig.json while writing `.less` and it didn't add anything.

Is there something for visual studio? Or maybe I should dump it and use some editor + gulp?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there will be an extension out there but it isn't too much work to create a Grunt/Gulp file to do your compiling for you. Task Runner Explorer will then manage the running of the file. Writing your own will give you the control and the flexibility that an extension will not.

Here is a sample using Grunt, taken from my post on the subject [Getting started with Grunt, SASS and Task Runner Explorer](http://iambacon.co.uk/blog/getting-started-with-grunt-sass-and-task-runner-explorer-visual-studio)

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Sass
        sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true, // Create source map
                outputStyle: 'compressed' // Minify output
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                  {
                      expand: true, // Recursive
                      cwd: "sass", // The startup directory
                      src: ["**/*.scss"], // Source files
                      dest: "stylesheets", // Destination
                      ext: ".css" // File extension 
                  }
                ]
            }
        },

        // Autoprefixer
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
                map: true // Update source map (creates one if it can't find an existing map)
            },

            // Prefix all files
            multiple_files: {
                src: 'stylesheets/**/*.css'
            }, 
        },

        // Watch
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['sass', 'autoprefixer']);
};
```